# If the joint density $f_{X_1,...,X_n}(x_1,...,x_n)$ is symmetric about the origin, does this imply that each marginal cdf $F_{X_i}(0)=1/2$?

Tags: joint-distribution, marginal-distribution, symmetry

If the joint density $f_{X_1,...,X_n}(x_1,...,x_n)$ is symmetric about the origin in the sense that for any $(x_1,...,x_n)$, it holds that

$f_{X_1,...,X_n}(x_1,...,x_n)=f_{X_1,...,X_n}(-x_1,...,-x_n)$

, does this imply that each marginal cdf satisfy $F_{X_i}(0)=1/2$?

Intuitively this seems true, as each marginal density will also be symmetric about the origin, which implies $F_{X_i}(0)=1/2$.

Comment: Are you assuming that the joint density is continuous? If not and something funny happens at the origin (or one of the coordinate planes), I'm not sure this will work. But if so, yeah, intuition suggests it should work.

Comment: Just integrate over the remaining $n-1$ variables, *QED.*